# Adding "date completed" timestamp in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, I would like to add a timestamp to a TODO marking the date completed. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set `org-log-done` to put the completion time in the `CLOSED` property.  The possible values are (as strings):

> nil     Don't add anything, just change the keyword
>
> time    Add a time stamp to the task
>
> note    Prompt for a note and add it with template `org-log-note-headings'

It is also possible to log any state change by adding "!" or "@" to the keyword definition.  For example,

```
TODO(t)" "NEXT(n)" "STARTED(s!)" "|" "DONE(d!/!)
```

will add a log entry whenever you change the state to `STARTED` or `DONE`, but not `TODO` or `NEXT`.  Using "@" instead of "!" will prompt for note when entering that state.